# Java - Oracle Weblogic 12c. I can't seem to get the proper path to connect my db file located in the resource folder

Tags: java, database, sqlite, oracle12c

My program structure. myApp -> src -> database -> myApp.db

```
String DB_LOCATION = "myApp/src/database/myApp.db";
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"+ DB_LOCATION);
```

This is the Console output

> java.sql.SQLException: path to 'myApp/src/database/myApp.db': 'C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\myApp' does not exist

I want to not point to the server path as i am going to deploy to another server.

What can i do?

I am using Eclispe FYI.